# How to put logic of editAction in showAction in Symfony 2 Doctrine generated CRUD?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an Symfony 2 project with Doctrine generated CRUD's (generated by 'app/console doctrine:generate:crud') for some database entities. In my specific case, I have entities like TariffMc, TariffMcServiceMcRelation. One TariffMc entity can belong to many TariffMcServiceMcRelation.

I have a showAction for TariffMc with default generated for this action code. And I want to list below all TariffMcServiceMsRelation, which belong to this TariffMc entity.

I was able to put some changes to showAction for TariffMc, so this page now renders TariffMc entity AND all related to this entity TariffMcServiceMcRelation entities. I tried many times, but I could not get the final result, that i need: I need to render showAction's result for TariffMc, and below there must be all related to this TariffMc TariffMcServiceMcRelation entities with possibility of editing and removing each TariffMcServiceMcRelation entity on the same page.

So, what I have now:

[image]

And what I need as a final result, roughly speaking:

[image]

**TariffMc 'show' template:**

```
{% extends 'menu.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>TariffMc</h1>

<table class="record_properties" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <td>{{ entity.id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Партнер</th>

<td>{{ entity.user }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Хэш</th>
            <td>{{ entity.hash }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>URL для уведомлений о статусах платежей</th>
            <td>{{ entity.notificationUrl }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    <ul class="record_actions">
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('system_settings_mc_tariffs') }}">
        Back to list
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('system_settings_mc_tariffs_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">
        Edit
    </a>
</li>
<li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
</ul>

{# Вывод в таблице всех записей из таблицы tariff_mc_service_mc_relation, которые относятся к данному тарифу #}
<h1>TariffMcServiceMcRelation</h1>
{% if relations %}
    <table class="records_list" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Оператор</th>
            <th>ID сервиса</th>
            <th>Стандартный успешный ответ на запрос КП</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>Комиссия</th>
            <th>Фильтр</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for relation in relations %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ relation.operator }}</td>
                <td>{{ relation.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ relation.successMessage }}</td>
                <td>{{ relation.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ relation.commission }}</td>
                <td>{{ relation.filter }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% else %}
    Нет отчислений для операторов
{% endif %}

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('system_settings_mc_tariff_mc_service_mc_relation_new') }}">
            Create TariffMcServiceMcRelation
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**TariffMcServiceMcRelation 'edit' template:**

```
<h1>TariffMcServiceMcRelation edit</h1>

{{ form(edit_form) }}

    <ul class="record_actions">
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('system_settings_mc_tariff_mc_service_mc_relation') }}">
        Back to list
    </a>
</li>
<li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
```

**TariffMc showAction:**

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:TariffMc')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find TariffMc entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Which way I need to modify **showAction()** for TariffMc and **show template** for TariffMc so I can get the result I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to make a hybrid show/edit page? Show should just show data, edit should just edit data.

The functionality to do what you are tring to do exists already:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection

in configureFormFields:

```
$formBuilder
    ->add('foobarRelationName', 'sonata_type_collection', array(),
        array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
        ))
```

Be aware that having many related entities available to edit this way can have a significant impact on performance and memory usage.

Edit: I have found the sonata documentation difficult to use and lacking information. Trial and error and lots of stackoverflow searching is your friend when trying to wrangle sonata field types to work the way you want with relations.

Comment: But can I implement functionality that I need without installing Sonata bundle? Here's list of bundles that I have installed in my project:
http://i.imgur.com/oCrBOSV.png

Comment: @koroveo Yes, you can implement that functionality yourself. However, implementing the functionality that you are talking about is non-trivial and involves making design choices and is far beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I've found general solution of my problem here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html